# How to generate a unique index for each possible configuration of an array

Tags: arrays, sorting, indexing

So I have an array that looks like this

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

It can be shuffled in any way like so

```
[6, 3, 4, 7, 1, 2, 8, 5]
```

How do I make a function that has a unique index for every possible configuration of these 8 elements? *emphasized text*(kind of like generating hashes) I've been trying to think of a way, and I can't seem to find it. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: I means, you could just concatenate the digits. 63471285.

Comment: @RaymondChen what happens on a list like `[1, 11]`?

Comment: @derpirscher I assumed the starting array was always "the numbers 1 through N". If it could be an arbitrary set of distinct numbers, you can rename the values so the smallest value is called 1, the next-smallest value is called 2, etc.

Comment: @RaymondChen  what if you have more than 10 values?

Comment: @derpirscher use two digits!